# Help me integrate this function using Simpson's rule

Tags: definite-integrals, simpsons-rule, indeterminate-forms

I have a question: compute

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$$

for $n=10$ divisions.

*I got the value $0.9127$ but I think its a bit too high.*

Comment: Why do you think so ?

Comment: because the actual value is approx  0.777

Comment: How does one integrate a question? Swallowing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx=\text{Si}(1)\approx0.946083.$$

[image]

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5cint_0%5e1%7bsin(x)%2fx%7ddx

Comment: The question is about Simpson's rule and Wolfram|Alpha can do [computations with Simpson's rule directly](http://goo.gl/HxDMFK).